# HighCharts: One Legend, Two Charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

I have four different  HighChart spline charts. All contain six series representing the six New England states. I want to click any legend and hide/show that series in all charts. I have tried legendclickitem but cannot get it to effect both charts.  Is what i am asking possible, if so can you point me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer:

Using Paweł FusIn code and in order to keep a legend on each chart I used the following code. You can click on any legend item and it updates all charts.

```
plotOptions: {
series: {
events: {
legendItemClick: function(event) {
if (this.visible) {
$('#container1').highcharts().series[this.index].hide(); 
$('#container2').highcharts().series[this.index].hide(); 
$('#container3').highcharts().series[this.index].hide(); 
$('#container4').highcharts().series[this.index].hide(); 
} 
else {
$('#container1').highcharts().series[this.index].show(); 
$('#container2').highcharts().series[this.index].show(); 
$('#container3').highcharts().series[this.index].show(); 
$('#container4').highcharts().series[this.index].show();
}
return false;
}
}
}
```

Comment: There is a more recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926516/grouping-legends-in-highcharts
(By using the linkedTo property.)

Comment: I do not believe the more recent answer actually solves this problem. This question is about two actual chart objects and how to share a legend between them. Paweł Fus's solution below still works great. Using linkedTo only appears to link two series' in a single chart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/teEQ3/

```
$('#container1').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        id: 'someId',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
$('#container2').highcharts({
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (event) {
                    var XYZ = $('#container1').highcharts(),
                        series = XYZ.get(this.options.id); //get corresponding series

                    if (series) {
                        if (this.visible) {
                            series.hide();
                        } else {
                            series.show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        id: 'someId',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

So the idea is to enable only in one chart legend, then in all respective charts hide corresponding series.

Comment: Does this work the same on pie/donut charts? I'm having some issues.

Comment: Yes and no. I mean, the idea is the same, but implementation is a bit different. Event is set in `point.events`, not in `series.events` and each point should have an ID, not series. Also, use `point.setVisible(vis)`, not `series.show()/hide()` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/teEQ3/86/