# Highcharts connecting scatter chart and pie chart with single legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to connect two different charts (a scatter and a pie chart) using the same legend. Upon printing to console, it seems like javascript is fetching the correct data of the correct pie chart. It just won't connect to the scatter chart legend. I tried what these answers suggested too: [HighCharts: One Legend, Two Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367653/highcharts-one-legend-two-charts) and [Multiple pie-charts in the same chart with HighCharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895619/multiple-pie-charts-in-the-same-chart-with-highcharts)

I'm using this code in my series.events of the scatter chart:

```
        events: {
                    legendItemClick: function (event) {
                        console.log(this.options.name);
                        var donut = $('#pie_chart').highcharts(),
                        series_arr = donut.series[0].data;
                        console.log(series_arr);
                        for (series in series_arr) {
                            if (this.options.name === series.name) {
                                if (this.visible) {
                                series.visible = true;
                            } else {
                                series.visible = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Am I missing something here? Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adway/gv7a6ngg/20/)

Comment: How about [linkedTo](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.linkedTo) option, which allows you to comibne two series into a one legend item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plotOptions` will be as

```
 plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: ''
  },
  series: {
    pointPadding: 0.2,
    borderWidth: 0,
    dataLabels: {
      //enabled: false
    },
    events: {
      legendItemClick: function(event) {
        console.log(this.options.name);
        var donut = $('#pie_chart').highcharts(),
          series_arr = donut.series[0].data;
        //console.log(series_arr);
        for (series in series_arr) {
          if (this.options.name === series_arr[series].name) {
            if (this.visible) {
              series_arr[series].setVisible(false);

            } else {
              series_arr[series].setVisible(true)

            }

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

[Forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxbsr3we/)

Error is

`this.options.name === series.name`

and it will be

`this.options.name === series_arr[series].name`

and use `setVisible()` to toggle