# Link two series object in Highcharts and add event

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple chart with six data objects, three lines and three bubbles. Each line shares the name with its corresponding bubble. How can I join each pair so that I can have an onClick event on either series to make them disappear?

I'm also not sure why disabling the legend is overriden:

```
  plotOptions: {
    showLegend: false
  }
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/K9WaT/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926516/grouping-legends-in-highcharts6516/grouping-legends-in-highcharts)? Maybe it can be useful to you.

But for hiding the legend I didn't find the `showLegend` property. To hide the legend there is a property of legend - [enabled](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.enabled):

```
legend: {
      enabled: false
}
```